How can I use LWP::UserAgent to get a .json file?
I wish to use LWP::UserAgent to get a JSON file from noaa.gov server.
Here is the script I am using:
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
no warnings 'uninitialized';

my ($ua, $res);

use LWP::UserAgent;

$ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(ssl_opts => { verify_hostname => 1 });
$res = $ua->get("https://services.swpc.noaa.gov/products/alerts.json");

# specify a CA path
$ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(
    ssl_opts => {
        SSL_ca_path     => '/etc/ssl/certs',
        verify_hostname => 1,
    }
);

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

print "Alert<br>\n";
print $res;
print "<br>\n";
print $ua;

exit;

Accessing the script from my server gives me the following:
Alert
HTTP::Response=HASH(0x8395e1c)
LWP::UserAgent=HASH(0x8445048)

Where do I go from here?

Note that you redefine $ua, so that's a completely different value than the one you used to make the request. I think you could take the example directly out of the LWP:UserAgent synopsis and you'd have what you want.


Remove one of those $ua 2. If you need to specify the SSL_ca_path (what you do in the second definition) then use that definition of $ua and remove the first one (and of course run $ua->get after it)


Do you really really need no warnings 'uninitialized'; ?  That catches a lot of problems, and some very subtle ones too.

("That catches..." by word "that" I mean the warnings for uninitialized)

According to the LWP::UserAgent POD for get:

The return value is a response object.

This is why you see the unexpected hex output.
The POD also shows usage of the decoded_content method:
use strict;
use warnings;
no warnings 'uninitialized';

my ($ua, $res);

use LWP::UserAgent;

$ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(ssl_opts => { verify_hostname => 1 });
$res = $ua->get("https://services.swpc.noaa.gov/products/alerts.json");

# specify a CA path
$ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(
    ssl_opts => {
        SSL_ca_path     => '/etc/ssl/certs',
        verify_hostname => 1,
    }
);
 
if ($res->is_success) {
    print $res->decoded_content;
}
else {
    die $res->status_line;
}

I get a long JSON output that starts like:

[{"product_id":"TIVA","issue_datetime":"2024-07-29 14:49:09.577",


Using the above, I now get a blank screen. No HASH - No Content. Any more ideas?

@Konabob: I get the json with this code

Note that the second $ua is defined after the request has been made, and as such isn't doing anything.

Interesting. I am seeing the following in my error log: 500 SSL negotiation failed:  at alert.cgi line 29.

Thanks for all of your feedback. I actually found a much simpler way to fetch the content from the url. All it took was these two lines of code:      my $url = 'https://services.swpc.noaa.gov/products/alerts.json';
$content = qx{wget --quiet --output-document=- $url};
